# How to unmarshal json to a struct without mapping all elements while retaining all information

Tags: json, go

I receive a JSON object from a queue. I want to process parts of that object and update it before sending on to another queue.

If I have an input of

```json
{
  "one": "data1",
  "two": "data2",
  "three": "data3",
  ...
}
```

I want to take `one` and `two` and calculate some information before adding the new outputs and sending on a message like

```json
{
  "one": "data1UPDATED",
  "two": "data2",
  "three": "data3",
  ...
  "extra_info": "extra"
}
```

To be able to process the data better I want to Unmarshal the JSON to a struct like

```golang
type Message struct {
 One string `json:one`
 Two string `json:two`
}
```

but don't want to map all of the fields as many of them are irrelevant to this app and others may change.

### Things I have tried

I have tried mapping all fields to `json.RawMessage`

```golang
type Message struct {
 One string `json:"one"`
 Two string `json:"two"`
 ExtraFields json.RawMessage `json:"-"`
}
```

However, when marshalling the struct the fields contained in `ExtraFields` are not included.

```json
{
  "one": "data1",
  "two": "data2"
}
```

I have also tried to write a custom unmarshaling that stores the full message in a struct with the useful message in one element and the other information in another field

```golang
type TmpMessage struct{
  Msg Message
  Others json.RawMessage
}
```

but this got very messy and I am hoping that there is a neater solution.

Is there a way to do this or is the only option to not unmarshal to a struct and just work with the raw `map[string]interface{}?`

Comment: `map[string]any` is a good choice when you're dealing with flexible JSON data. You can use a third-party library as well. Here's a library I wrote that might help: https://github.com/bserdar/jsonom

Comment: There is no such way. Usually, if you need something like this, it's customary to write a custom unmarshaler code which first unmarshals into a map and then picks out individual fields. Note that you can unmarshal into a `map[string]json.RawMessage` which could make unmarshaling of values into variables of user-defined tag-annotated types easier–for an example, see [this](https://go.dev/play/p/qvNwIyotqqh). In a more realistic code you'd delete "known and parsed" entries from the map, so that in the end it contains only "unprocessed" fields.

Comment: Another approach which might be sometimes applicable is to unmarshal into a `map[string]interface{}`/`map[string]any`, then examine the result to decide which one of multiple possible "formats" ("shapes", whatever) the data is, and then unmarshal the source document again–into a variable of the corresponding tag-annotated user-defined type. This would parse the source document twice but arguably simplify the code in return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a custom unmarshaler, something like:

https://go.dev/play/p/53r1hqmbuJi

```
func (m *Message) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
  tmp := make(map[string]interface{})
  if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &tmp); err != nil {
    return err
  }
  t := reflect.TypeOf(*m)
  for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
    f := t.Field(i)
    if f.Name != "ExtraFields" {
      jsonTag := f.Tag.Get("json")
      // this part should probably by a type switch...
      reflect.ValueOf(m).Elem().Field(i).SetString(tmp[jsonTag].(string))
      delete(tmp, jsonTag)
    }
  }
  var err error
  m.ExtraFields, err = json.Marshal(tmp)
  return err
}
```

Comment: I quite like this approach as it is all a bit more self-contained rather than having to constantly retrieve the elements from the map where there always needs to be a nil check etc.